# Mounting TYPO3 FAL storage with another domain

Tags: typo3

Using TYPO3 6.1.9 (will be updated soon to latest 6.2).

Is it currently possible to use a FAL storage with another domain? The webspace looks like this:

```
path-to-web-directories/
- maindomain.com/
- - fileadmin/
- - typo3/
- sub.domain.com/
- - files.txt
```

In the TYPO3 backend I created a file storage for the directories `path-to-web-directories/maindomain.com/fileadmin/` and one for `path-to-web-directories/sub.domain.com/`. This is really great and work so far. I can manage the files in both storages.

But now if I set a link to a file located in sub.domain.com, the URL looks like this:

```
http://www.maindomain.com/sub.domain.com/files.txt
```

instead of

```
http://sub.domain.com/files.txt
```

Ist this issue a part of TYPO3 or can I configure this with realUrl (which I'm using)? And how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem:

The URL is generated in the class TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Driver\LocalDriver->getPublicUrl
In this case an own extension with a new resource driver is needed.